# BackgroundWorker DoWork delegate fails when using XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, backgroundworker, xmlreader

I'm trying to read an XML stream using `BackgroundWorker`:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(serverStream);

            while (r.Read())
            {
  output something using backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress object
            }
    }
```

I call this using `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(null)` in a button click event.

The program compiles and runs fine but the process stalls at `XmlReader.Create`. No errors, but it says that it can not evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack. So, it's probably waiting for the process to finish.

The problem is that if I do this directly from the mouse click without using the backgroundWorker object, the program runs just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: How do you pass "clientSocket" ? Are you 100% sure it's the same and not used outside the bgw?

Comment: Can you post the calling code (around RunWorkerAsync(null) ) ?

Comment: (After the comments below) - post all code relating to clientSocket. Without it thos question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx) states that `XmlReader.Create` reads the first few bytes to determine the encoding.
I think the problem is, that your stream doesn't return any data. This might be the case because another thread already read all the data.

Comment: But that exactly is the problem. If I don't use the backgroundWorker, it works just fine. For example, if I enclose the method inside the mouse click event, it runs as it should. Is there something I need to do to make xmlReader work with backgroundWorker?

Comment: @Henk: Your comment implies that you think I didn't read his question properly. You are wrong. Read my answer again: "This might be the case because another thread already read all the data.". When he is using his code on the UI thread, there (most likely) is only one thread. Now he introduces the BackgroundWorker and he has two threads. Directly after invoking the BackgroundWorker, the UI thread could continue and read the network stream and that could cause his problem.

Comment: @Daniel: The only place I invoke the xmlReader.Create is in backgroundWorker. Is it still possible that a UI thread is reading the stream? If yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: @snaee: Please show the code of the button click handler as already asked by Henk.

Comment: Here it is: private void startScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(null);}

Comment: @snaee: is clientSocket used elsewhere?

Comment: No, it's not used anywhere else. I included MessageBox.Show() method in the BackgroundWorker1 and it indicates that the process runs without the issue I described earlier. As long as I keep on clicking on the OK button of MessageBox, the program keeps on running fine. I then replaced MessageBox with the backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress() method and created private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {readTagID.Text = "y";} but that does not seem to do anything (nothing is written in the text box) even though WorkerReportsProgress is set to true.

Comment: @snaee I guess you probably call ProgressChanged too frequently that will cause some [problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/15187f2d-3ef3-404d-abd4-b2b421aed26d/reportprogress-dont-call-it-more-frequently-than-1-second?forum=vbgeneral). You could add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);` before `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the XML reader creation is getting blocked on reading the stream.

- There might be a deadlock situation whereby the server stream will not send bytes until the background worker thread has performed some task (seems unlikely however)
- As @Daniel Hilgarth suggests, perhaps another thread has fully read the stream previously?

There could also be some synchronisation issues here. Try adding a lock statement around the code, e.g.:-

```
private readonly object streamLocker = new object();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    lock(streamLocker)
    {
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(serverStream);

        while (r.Read())
        {
          //  output something using backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried lock statement but that didn't work. As others (@Henk...) have also suggested, the backgroundWorker might be trying to access the stream after the UI stream has read the data. This could be an issue but I don't know where the UI thread is reading the data since the only place I invoke XMLReader.Create is in the backgroundWorker....